# ST_DWithin function gives the same value, while trying to join two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to join two tables based on their geometries, and getting the same values for columns:

```sql
select poly.block_code, ST_X(points.geom),  ST_X(points.geom)
from public.us_blocks10_coordinates poly
join public.usgs_2 points
on St_DWithin(poly.geom, ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(points.geom, 102008), 4269), 0) 
limit 10
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are printing `st_x` twice so it is expected that the values would be the same.

Second, we see that when printing `st_x(point.geom)`, the coordinate really looks like being degrees. However, in the `st_dwithin` part, there is the statement `ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(points.geom, 102008), 4269)` which implies that the points are in CRS 102008, whose unit is in meters, and that you then transform to 4269 (degrees). Both statements are incompatible, and it seems that the `set_srid` statement is wrong and therefore the result of `st_transform` is also wrong and so is the result of `st_dwithin`, and you end up with the ID of whatever polygon is located over the wrong points, near `-96;40`, the projection [center coordinate](https://epsg.io/102008).

Maybe you would just need `St_DWithin(poly.geom, ST_SetSRID(points.geom,4269), 0)`

Let's note that you could use `st_intersects` here instead of `st_dwithin`